# cakephp 3 method Delete in rest routes

Tags: php, rest, cakephp

In routes.php I add

```
 $routes->extensions(['json']);
 $routes->resources('News');
```

When in postman I put url and chose method `GET`, framework redirect me to `index()` action, if I chose method `POST` framework redirect me to `add()` method, but if I chose method `DELETE` I go to `index()` again. How can I go to delete() action if I chose method `DELETE`?

//////////////////
I understood what my problem. All working good. Problem was in my url. I chose method `Delete` and my url is `rest.app/api/news`. That why framework redirect me to `index()` action but if I put `rest.app/api/news/1`
and get method `Delete` I go to `delete()` action

Comment: There's nothing that you'd need to do, other than sending a proper `DELETE` request. Go for some debugging and check for possible errors and redirects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REST should work as follows:

GET /users      list users.

GET /users/5    show user 5.

POST /users     add user.

DELETE /users/5 delete user 5.

In your controller action, check for the request method, and call the appropriate code.

Here's an index action in one of my own rest controllers:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    switch ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
        case 'POST':
            $json = $this->createRecord();
            break;
        case 'PUT':
        case 'PATCH':
        case 'DELETE':
        $json = $this->sendJSONResponse(array('error' => 'Invalid HTTP Method, did you send an ID?'), self::RESPONSE_NOT_FOUND);
            break;
        case 'GET':
        default:
            $json = $this->listRecords();
            break;
    }
    return $json;
}
```

Comment: That's what connecting resource routes (as shown in the OPs example) is good for, it creates routes that connect to the proper actions based on the request method. Side note: you should't fiddle with superglobals directly in CakePHP, that will become especially annoying in the testing environment, instead use the abstracted access methods provided by the framework (like the request object).

Comment: Absolutely regarding the global $_SERVER var. If Cake has a request object, get that value from that instead! :-)